# Xamarin Forms Listview ItemSelected NavigationPage Two Times

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've a listview and when click list item, I want to open the item detail page. But when I more than one click quickly its opening two navigationpage. My detail Page's const have a async method.
Here is my code.

How to block multiple clicks?

MyPage.xaml

```
    <ListView      
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    SeparatorColor="#e7e5e5"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"      
    ItemsSource="{Binding ExpecterDemands}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemSelected="InfiniteListView_ItemSelected">
```

MyPage.xaml.cs

```
async void InfiniteListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e`
    {         
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to use `ItemTapped` instead of `ItemSelected`.

`ItemSelected` will fire multiple times.

`ItemTapped`, on the other hand, only fires once when the item is tapped.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent double taps you could add a local bool to prevent it from running more than once, just make sure it gets set back to false in the finally statement.

```
bool _isRunning;

async void InfiniteListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e
{
    if (_isRunning)
        return;

    _isRunning = true;

    try
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());
    }
    finally
    {
        _isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i cannot use `ItemSelected` and i fixed it like this for `ItemTapped`
Create a common method `StopMultipleTaps` which will disable ListView for 500 ms,so that another fast click will not captured.

```
public void StopMultipleTaps(ListView listView)
    {
        listView.IsEnabled = false;
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), () => {
            listView.IsEnabled = true;
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Call above method at the very start of ItemTapped handler:

```
    async void InfiniteListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e`
    { 
        StopMultipleTaps((ListView)sender);       
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());
    }
```